# Is it safe to observe a keyPath when an object along the path may change?

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

Is it safe to implement KVO as such:

```
[self addObserver:self
       forKeyPath:@"restaurant.oldestOrder.patron.frustrationLevel"
          options:0 context:nil];
```

…when you know that `oldestOrder` might change or become nil, and that previous `oldestOrders` might become deallocated?

Comment: PS. Never use a nil context.  Use an integer casted to a (void *), and then keep all the contexts at the top of the header in an enum.

Comment: I just learned about that today @iluvcapra. Something to do with being able to tell which class a notification is intended for when there are subclasses involved, right?

Comment: Right, if you are observing @"oldestOrder" and you subclass the object, and the subclass also observes @"oldestOrder", the `observeValue:` message will arrive at an object but it won't know which logic to evaluate, or that it should do *both*.   You should also always use `removeObserver:forKeyPath:context:` if you're building against 10.7 (don't ask me why it took so long for them to implement that).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Executive summary:

You never need to add an observer twice for the same key just because keys in the middle changed, `NSKeyValueObserving` does this for you.

As long as your `-oldestOrder` method doesn't return a dangling pointer, nothing should break.

---

The way KVO works is when you add yourself as an observer, the observer is added to a list on the observed object, in the form of an `NSObservationInfo` object.  Easy.  An `NSObservationInfo` object is just a raw key (not a path), an object to watch, an observer to call, a pointer to the context you passed, and some other bookkeeping stuff.

When you observe a path of keys, the observer relationships are observed through respective `NSObservationInfo` objects, which are held in the list on the called object, as if the whole path was a property of the object you called `-addObserver` on.

In your example `self` observes `restaurant`, but the `addObserver:` method then creates `NSObservationInfo` objects in the background that are added as observers for each respective object down the path, and these are also added to your self's list of observers.

When you observe `@"A.B.C.D"` of an object, it creates four `NSObservationInfo` objects, one for each key relation, and these are added to each key on the path as an observer, so you get an `NSObservationInfo` object watching `A` of the called, one watching `B` of `A`, one watching `C` of `B`, etc.  When one of these NSObservationInfo objects observes a change, it passes this along to the original `-addObserver` caller as a change to the *entire* keypath.

(This is an implementation detail but it should help the explanation.)

When an object in the middle of the path is nil'd or removed, `-willChangeValueForKey` notices this and dutifully removes the `NSObservationInfo` objects as observers, along the path after the nil'd object.  These `NSObservationInfo` objects still exist though, and they still know what keys they want to see, and when `-didChangeValueForKey` is called, it will look at the new value for the key and if it has key names matching the ones that it's chain of `NSObservationInfo` objects is looking for, it will attach them as the new observers.

So, when any element along the path `@"restaurant.oldestOrder.patron.frustrationLevel"` changes, you will get a change notification, but the `NSKeyValueObserving` machinery will attempt to reestablish a relationship with the key at the end of that path after the change, and any subsequent change.

Here's [Cocoatron's implementation of this](http://code.google.com/p/cocotron/source/browse/Foundation/NSKeyValueCoding/NSKeyValueObserving.m?r=0af4b82c19ff763198f6971e0dec4ca257d58934), you can see how it works yourself.

Comment: That caveat is, of course, that all the properties in the key path must only be modified in a KVO-compliant manner. You can screw KVO's housekeeping up, otherwise.